# Strange ahref tag before <html> in wordpress - Have I been hacked?

Tags: php, wordpress, malware

In google search my site comes up as hacked! It's a wordpress site.
When I inspect the html content on chrome or firefox I see nothing out of the ordinary, but when I fetch from google I see the following before the main html tag:

```
<a href=http://healthandmovement.co.uk/hgqn/p5sh5.php?ldhzln=gazprom-energy-contact-number>4pnk</a>, <a href=http://thisandthatevents.com/7ftw/zcgep.php?ldhzln=industrial-automation-ppt-templates>htdvl</a>, <a href=http://accessdatabasetutorial.com/8whn/zuofy.php?ldhzln=lufthansa-catalogue-2017>7yn5p</a>, <a href=http://businessbaristabook.com/dcp6/eemht.php?ldhzln=huawei-b310s-manual>eddp</a>, <a href=http://www.coffeemegusta.ru/media/editors/codemirror/mode/clojure/imqn/th3qs.php?ldhzln=openai-gym-spaces>nuzke</a>, ...
```

Some more junk and then (warning, link without query string is NSFW):

```
... <a href=http://medindia.co/ye7s/mvs1y.php?ldhzln=road-rhino-kits>2fg</a>, 1<!DOCTYPE html>
```

And on the next line:

```
<html lang="en-GB" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" class="html_stretched responsive av-preloader-disabled av-default-lightbox  html_header_top html_logo_left html_main_nav_header html_menu_right html_slim html_header_sticky html_header_shrinking html_header_transparency html_mobile_menu_phone html_header_mobile_behavior html_header_searchicon_disabled html_content_align_center html_header_unstick_top_disabled html_header_stretch_disabled html_minimal_header html_entry_id_10 ">
```

Have I been hacked? Do I have a malware on my wordpress site?

I have tried your regular wordpress site checkers like google safe browsing, sucuri and the wordfence plugin and the exploite scanner plugin and they have found nothing.

Comment: Try disabling plugins one by one and check. If it is still the same, check function.php in your theme directory.

Comment: Well, if you haven't created those liks then yeah it seems so - they're mostly ads and js miners. But don't panic. Scan your files for shells / malware and if you have a recent clean backup use it. Then you can use a tool like [wpscan](https://github.com/wpscanteam/wpscan) to identify the vulnerability, and finally make sure to keep your themes and plugins updated.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. tried disabling all plugins ... no joy.

Comment: @Parshant Nothing in function.php either.

Comment: @t.m.adam any hits on how to scan files for shells / malware?

Comment: I can't recommend a specific tool, but any decent antivirus should be able to detect malicious code. You can also check manually any recently created or modified files.

Comment: Install [WordFence](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/) plugin and scan if your site is infected, this is the best way to check.